# Clear facebook session on ios after permission revoked on facebook website

Tags: ios, facebook, session, permissions

I am using facebook sdk 3.11 on iOS 6.
I have the following problem:
I opening a session for readpermissions and after this I do a requestNewPublishPermissions. Everthing works fine.
Now I revoke the publish permission on facebook and then retry to use the fbrequest which needs the publish permission. I get an FBErrorCategoryPermissions error. That seems ok but now I want to re-request the publish permission and this doesn't work or I don't know how.

I tried: [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation] and start over the upper process but this doesn't work. I makes no difference if I revoke the permission on facebook website or facebook app.

If I delete the app from apps on facebook the re-opening (update) of the session works fine.

What can I do to re-request the revoked permission?